# Falha na instalação da extensão do C# no VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image]
Olá, estou com um problema para instalar a extensão do C# no meu PC, ele é um pouco antigo e tem 32bits, e quando tento instalar diz que a extensão não é suportada. Gostaria de saber se tem como instalar alguma versão antiga para resolver o problema.

Comment: Vai funcionar normal, você só não vai conseguir debugar

Comment: Isso é só um aviso amigo, a extensão ficou mesmo instalada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mensagem apresentada é um aviso de que não irá funcionar o debug, mas a extensão foi instalada com sucesso! Todas as demais funções funcionarão normalmente.

A extensão não consegue debugar em um Sistema Operacional 32 bits e por issues abertos no repositório da extensão, parece que no passado não havia suporte para debug em 32 bits já no vscode e não terá suporte para tal no futuro. [Debugger doesn't support x86 Windows](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/844).